# PHP Closure On Class Instance

Tags: php, oop, closures, anonymous-function

If I have a class like:

```
class MyClass
{
   public function foo() 
   {
      echo "foo";
   }
}
```

And then outside of the class instantiate it and try to create an anonymous function in it:

```
$mine = new MyClass();

$mine->bar = function() {
   echo "bar";
}
```

And then try to call it like `$mine->bar()`, I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyClass::bar() in ...

**How can I create an anonymous function / closure on a class instance?**

*Aside: Before you tell me I should rethink my logic or use interfaces and OOP properly, in my case, it's a convenience method that applies to this specific instance of a bastardized class in an attempt to clean-up a legacy procedural application. And yes, I'm using PHP 5.3+*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my blog article here: http://blog.flowl.info/2013/php-container-class-anonymous-function-lambda-support/

You need to add a magic [`__call`](http://php.net/__call) function:

```
public function __call($func, $args) {
    return call_user_func($this->$func, $args);
}
```

**The problem is that within this construct you can call private methods from public scope.**
I suggest **not** to simply add new variables to a class that **are not defined**. You can avoid this using magic `__set` functions and *catch* all undefined variables in a container (= array, like in my blog post) and change the call_user_func behaviour to call only inside the array:

```
// inside class:
public $members = array();

public function __call($func, $args) {
    // note the difference of calling only inside members:
    return call_user_func($this->members[$func], $args);
}
```

Comment: Great! It just so happened the class extended a class implementing magic methods so it was no sweat adding this in. One addition I made is to check with `is_callable()` before actually calling it. Thanks!

Comment: this can be extended in some ways, but you get the idea behind it B-)

Answer (score 1):

**__call**

This will work.

```
class Foo {

    public $bar;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = function()
        {
            echo 'closure called';
        };

        $this->bar();
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        return call_user_func($this->$method, $args);
    }

}

new Foo();
```

Comment: First come - first served :)

Answer (score 1):

The function IS being created.
PHP has a problem with calling it.

Dirty, but works:

```
$f = $mine->bar;
$f();
```

Comment: Interesting. Reminds me of the issue with dynamic namespaces. You have to put it in a variable first before instantiating like $ns = "\\App\\Lib\\" . $myClass; $object = new $ns();`

Comment: @cillosis you can (at least in PHP 5.4) use brackets: `$object = new {$ns}();` same with fluent classes: does not work: `$x = new xxx()->method();` does work: `$x = (new xxx())->method();`